# How can I view all Java Processes running on a windows box using CMD prompt

Tags: java, process, command-line

On CMD prompt, I am trying to list all Java processes with the CMD line arguments.

In short, I want to list all Java processes which have jmxremote.port set on cmd prompt.

What's the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 2):

**jps**  (from your *jdk_home/bin*) will list all the PIDS along with the "description" which is frequently, but not always, the main class. e.g.

```
c:\>jps
13436 Unknown
14092 Unknown
4280
16960 Jps
4284 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
9976 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
```